# numpy swap multiple elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array containing a random spread of 1s and 0s. I want to replace all the 1s with a 0 and all the zeros with a 1.

```
arr[arr == 0] = 2
arr[arr == 1] = 0
arr[arr == 2] = 1
```

I'm currently having to use a temporary value (2 in this case) in order to avoid all the 0s becoming 1s and then subsequently making the entire array full of 0s.
Is there a more elegant/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate and store your Boolean indexers before overwriting any values:

```
ones = a == 1
zeros = a == 0

a[ones] = 0
a[zeros] = 1
```

The solution also works if you have values other than `0` and `1`.

---

If you don't need an *in place* solution, you can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where):

```
a = np.where(ones, 0, np.where(zeros, 1, a))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that's very specific to your problem, but should also be very fast. Given the array:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

You can subtract 1 from all the values and multiply by negative 1:

```
>>> (a-1)*-1
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: `(a - 1) * -1` distributes to `-a + 1` or `1 - a` which is a bit clearer (also a decent bit faster)

Answer (score 3):

For your specific values bitwise xor with 1.

```
In [19]: a=np.random.randint(2, size=10)

In [18]: a
Out[18]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])

In [19]: a^1
Out[19]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

A more general solution for int types.

```
In [62]: convert=np.array([1,0])

In [63]: convert[a]
Out[63]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Changing the contents of the 'convert' array means a range of values can be mapped.  The result uses the contents of array 'a' as the index into the array 'convert'.

Comment: Good solutions! Is the indexing logic you are using in the second one a case of fancy indexing, or does it go by another name?

Comment: The numpy documentation shows this as Advanced Indexing -> Integer Array Indexing. [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html).  Both methods came from experience using Forth rather than Python/numpy.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
>>> np.where(a == 0, 1, 0) # read as (if, then, else)
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

... or alternatively negate `a` and do some typecasting.

```
>>> (~a.astype(bool)).astype(int)
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

(IPython) timings: not much difference.

```
>>> a = np.eye(1000, dtype=int)
>>> %timeit np.where(a == 0, 1, 0)
1.56 ms ± 2.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit (~a.astype(bool)).astype(int)
1.74 ms ± 87.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Timings for other people's answers:

```
>>> %timeit a^1 # Tls Chris
920 µs ± 31.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit np.array([1, 0])[a] # Tls Chris
1.4 ms ± 102 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit (a - 1)*-1 # sacul
1.57 ms ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit 1 - a # user3483203
905 µs ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

My opinion: `a^1` and `1 - a` are clean, elegant and fast. Using `np.where` works with any values you might want to swap.

Answer (score 1):

If an efficient solution is more important than an elegant one, you could write a quite simple `Numba` solution.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit()
def nb_where(arr):
  for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
      if arr[i,j]==1:
        arr[i,j] = 0
      else:
        arr[i,j] = 1
  return arr
```

**Timings**

```
a = np.eye(1000, dtype=int)
np.where(a == 0, 1, 0) #timgeb    -> 2.06ms 
a^1                    #Tls Chris -> 1.31ms 
nb_where(a)                       -> 152 µs
```